# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package v2021

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying a simple database connection.

"""

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='options',
                                     user='root',
                                     password='xxxxx')
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select database();")
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    print("You're connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

"""

This works - once - if I uninstall and reinstall MySQL.  When I try it a second time if fails to the above Traceback.  When it works I've tried a simple read of some of the data.  This also works only once per reinstall.

"""

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='options',
                                     user='root',
                                     password=xxxxxx)

    sql_select_Query = "SELECT command”  (my SELECT command is lengthy so I’ve omitted it)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    # get all records
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Total number of rows in table: ", cursor.rowcount)

    print("\nPrinting each row")
    for row in records:
        print("col1 = ", row[0], )
        print("col2 = ", row[1])
        print("col3  = ", row[2])
        print("col4= ", row[3], "\n")

except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

"""

I've done the MySQL installation of the server, workbench, and connector (3x).

I'm using Windows 10 Home with the latest Anaconda release.

Python 3.8.11 (default, Aug  6 2021, 09:57:55) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

I’ve uninstalled ALL mysql entries in the pip list and reinstalled them (multiple times).

I have no issues accessing the database from MySQL Workbench.

(base) PS C:\Users\WARNE> pip list

Package                            Version

---

mysql                              0.0.3

mysql-connector-python             8.0.26

mysqlclient                        2.0.3

(base) PS C:\Users\WARNE> conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
…this continued to fail

I've tried about every solution in all of the related questions without any luck.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went back to basics and re-installed, went to very simple code, etc. and this started working.  This seems to be a weakness in python-MySQL interworking.  This was frustrating.